# How to send javascript variables to code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I want to send my id value to code behind to fill a listbox.

Here I call my id value:

```
function dialogOpen(id) {
    $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
}
```

And here I use this id value normally:

```
  var contentstring = p.name + '<div ID="pageopen" onclick="dialogOpen('+p.pid+')"> <br>Detaylar </div>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery ajax and make request to some POST operation either submit form or request to POST operation in web service or asp.net mvc controller

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/